# Getting version of Ruby when a feature was added

Tags: ruby

Is anyone aware of how to retrieve the exact version (major, minor, patch) that a specific feature was added/removed/altered to the Ruby language?

Obviously one could comb through the history to find out, which is not ideal, and can be cumbersome to navigate. Was curious if anyone might know a better way to do it, as the documentation doesn't state when a method, class, etc. was added.

When documenting my own gems with YARD, it is easy to just add a `@since` tag to clearly show when something was added, but the Ruby API doesn't seem to have any such mechanism in its own documentation.

When writing gems, it is obviously handy to know such details when managing dependencies, and I was hoping there was a simpler solution, such as simply typing a method name into a website, and seeing the exact version it was added.

To clarify, basically a "changelog" for any item. For example, type in method name, see log of when it was added, changed, deprecated, removed, etc.

A prime example would be something akin to .NET Core's [Reverse Package Search](https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net).

Comment: You need a precise definition of "feature" in your opening sentence. Presumably this includes the introduction of new modules and methods, but what about changes to the functionality of methods (e.g., giving `Emerable#min` an optional argument in v2.2 or the overhaul of `Refinements`in v2.1), deprecating objects (e.g, `Fixnum` in v2.4), changing properties of objects (e.g., maintaining key insertion order for hashes in v1.9.1), removing bugs, changing explanations of exceptions, making methods more efficient and so on?

Comment: No, I intend to keep it defined exactly as it is, because that is exactly how I mean it. I mean a way to know when any "feature" is added, removed, altered... anything. This included methods, classes, syntax changes. I know how to find these things, but it is not as simple as I believe it should be. I intend for the word "feature" to be broad and encompass nearly anything, do not want it to be more specific.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to effectively construct a method `m` such that `m(f)` returns the version of (MRI, say) Ruby in which feature `f` appeared. That would obviously require an ambiguous way of specifying features. That could be done for, say, instance methods (e.g., `Array#sum`) but would would be problematic for "features" in general. For example, how would one identify a bug, much less determine when it was fixed? I'm now thinking you are instead just asking for suggestions on how certain features might be traced to a particular Ruby version. (cont.)

Comment: Yes, exactly, not actual getting version information from within Ruby code, but a more detailed or easier to way to track changes in the language other than burrowing through tons of history files and news on each release. I was hoping there existed a more comprehensive and user-friendly way of tracking changes to the actual Ruby language. It is quite possible nothing exists, and this is all just hopes and dreams, lol.

Answer (score 1):

I was just doing this, unfortunately my answer is what you were *hoping* to avoid.

I was looking through history, but able to use GitHub's handy Blame feature to help track down when a specific line was edited. With this I could open the file in question click "Blame" and see when it was last edited/created.

Was a great way to track down when `Exception2MessageMapper` was added to the [standard library](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/lib). It was 17 years ago, as part of v1.4.0:

https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blame/trunk/lib/e2mmap.rb#L55

Comment: Yeah, the closet I have gotten is searching feature, and browsing the "NEWS" articles on GitHub where it mentions it... Still not ideal.